# jQuery - Reset value on keyup

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my jQuery code. I have this script, where users first choose what type of exposure they would like to add clicks to.

When they have chosen the exposure, the jQuery code will show how many clicks they have of that exposure.

The problem is, if an user first selects an exposure, where they have 0 clicks, and then select an exposure where they have over 0 clicks, my keyup script will just write "0".

An example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2FSzH/

Please try to first select "Standard Exposure", then choose "Micro Exposure" and try to write example "500" in the input field. My script will not allow this.

This is the code that controls the numbers only script:

```
if(value == 1){
        $('.available-clicks').html(clicksmicro);
        $('.numbersonly').keyup(function () { 
            var inputval = $('.numbersonly').val();
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
            if(inputval > clicksmicro){
                $('.numbersonly').val('0');
            }
        });
     }else if(value == 2){
        $('.available-clicks').html(clicksmini);
        $('.numbersonly').keyup(function () { 
            var inputval = $('.numbersonly').val();
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
            if(inputval > clicksmini){
                $('.numbersonly').val('0');
            }
        });
     }else if(value == 3){
        $('.available-clicks').html(clicksstandard);
        $('.numbersonly').keyup(function () { 
            var inputval = $('.numbersonly').val();
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
            if(inputval > clicksstandard){
                $('.numbersonly').val('0');
            }
        });
     }else if(value == 4){
        $('.available-clicks').html(clicksextended);
        $('.numbersonly').keyup(function () { 
            var inputval = $('.numbersonly').val();
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
            if(inputval > clicksextended){
                $('.numbersonly').val('0');
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: Beaten to it for adding `off` but I have revised your code slightly here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FSzH/2/) so I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: @Jonathan I see your jQuery code is quite different than mine. What improvements/changes did you do?

Comment: ignoring `if ($('.numbersonly').val() > clicks[which].value) {` which simply retains the value in the `numbersonly` input unless it is more than the maximum specified value. The remaining changes make use a JavaScript object to specify the number of allowed clicks instead of duplicating the code for each of the possible selected values. This means should you wish to add more options, for example *clicksnano* all you would need to do would be to update the *clicks* object and the code would handle the rest for you.

Comment: Or you could add a `data` attribute to your options and check against that - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FSzH/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding events to `keyUp` without deleting the ones wich are already bound it. Try to unbind them **before** attach a new one. For example, you can use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
 $('.numbersonly').off('keyup');
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zt6n/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you add new event listener each time when user changes dropdown. This leads to many simultaneous handlers and result is unpredictable. To avoid it, you need to do `.off("keyup")` right before assign new handler. However, there is another issue. You have a huge pieces of equals code. I suggest you to move maximum value to data-attribute and work with one event handler, binded once.